# Relocation errors when linking a static library with shared library

Tags: g++, shared-libraries, static-libraries, mingw-w64

I am trying to generate a shared library (libgenerated.so) using g++ . The shared library uses some functionality that comes from a third party static library (libmystatic.a). For which I am linking the static library with the shared library as :

`g++ -shared -o libgenerated.so $(OBJ_FILES) -lmystatic`

The above command returns the following relocation error for the static library:

`` relocation R_X86_64_32S against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC ``

Which points out that the object files in the static library needs to be compiled with `-fpic` flag. I am unable to understand why creating a Windows dll using the same static library (compiled for windows without -fpic) works ? I am using x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ for the Windows DLL.

Thoughts from experts....

Comment: Because PIC is the default on Windows, so you don't need this flag.

Comment: Does this mean that object files compiled with mingw are by default position independent ?

Comment: Yes this is my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

> Which points out that the object files in the static library needs to be compiled with -fpic flag.

Exactly: on `x86_64` you *must* compile code that is linked into a shared library with `-fPIC` of `-fPIC`.

> I am unable to understand why creating a Windows dll using the same static library (compiled for windows without -fpic) works ?

There are two reasons:

1. On Windows, position-independent code is the default. So you get code compiled *as if* `-fPIC` was on command line regardless of whether that flag was on compile line or not.
2. The requirement to have position-independent code is architecture-specific. You *can* build a 32-bit `i*86` shared library *without* `-fPIC` (this is ill-advised, but it works). On `x86_64` (64-bit) Linux, you can't -- it simply can't work on that architecture.